# REST strategy for overloading GET verb

Tags: rest

Consider a need to create a GET endpoint for fetching Member details using either of 4 options (It's common in legacy application with RPC calls)

1. Get member by ID
2. Get member by SSN
3. Get member by a combination of Phone and LastName (both must be passed)

What's a recommended strategy to live the REST spirit and yet provide this flexibility?

Some options I could think of are:

**Parameters Based**

```
/user/{ID}  
/user?ssn=?
/user?phone=?&lname=?
```

**Separate Endpoints**

```
/user/{ID}
/user/SSN/{SSNID}
/user/{lname}/{phone}
```

**RPC for custom**

```
/user/{ID}
/user/findBySSN/
/user/findbycontact/
```

Comment: As clients shouldn't interpret URIs but only invoke them based on decisions done via the accompanying link relation name it doesn't really matter what style you use. It is more important that you name the link relation name in a way that gives clients some sense whether to invoke the URI or not. You even could encode the parameters i.e. via base64,  a custom algorithm or what not or use a tiny-url actually. The server at least needs to know how to extract the actual parameters somehow.

Comment: It might not be wise to put SSN's in urls. This is pretty sensitive information, and urls are kinda leaky. Don't risk the privacy of your users.

Answer (score 0):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers.

For example, think about how you would do this on the web.  You would provide forms, one for each set of search criteria.  The consumer would choose which form to use, and submit the form, without ever knowing what the URI is.

In the case of HTML forms, there are specific processing rules for describing how the form information will be copied into the URI.  The form takes on the aspect of a [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).

> A URI Template provides both a structural description of a URI space and, when variable values are provided, machine-readable instructions on how to construct a URI corresponding to those values.

But there aren't any rules saying that restrict the server from providing a URI template that directs the client to copy the variable values into path segments rather than into the query string.

In other words, in REST, the server retains control of its own URI space.

You might sometimes prefer to use [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) segments because of their hierarchical nature, which may be convenient if you want the client to use [relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2)  of [relative references](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) in your representations.

Answer (score 0):

REST ≠ pretty URLs. The two are orthogonal.
Your question is about the latter, I feel.

Whilst the other answers have been good, if you want your API to work with HTML forms, go with query parameters on the collection `/user` resource for all fields, even for ID (assuming a human is typing these in based on information they are getting from sheets of paper on their desk, etc.)

If your server is able to produce links to each record, always produce canonical links such as `/users/{id}`, don't duplicate data under different URLs.